# removing specific character from specific column in unix file

Tags: awk, sed

I have unix file with headerrs in csv format like below

```
group_n,node_n ,product_n
schema_name,report_pltform,My Name, is, Ma
```

Expected out pout
o/p

```
group_n,node_n ,product_n
schema_name,report_pltform,My Name is Ma
```

Need to remove "," from col3 and keep , separated values between the column headers and values. Any help ?

Comment: tried below echo col1, col2,  col3, col4 | tr -d \' | sed "s/<table_name>.//g" | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' > test but not
 working

Comment: So, it's not a comma separated file., but whitespace separated? Please show the exact expected result

Comment: ```col1,col2,col3,col4
     abc,efg,  hij  lmn ```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Does `awk '{gsub(/,/," ",$3)}1' the_file` do what you want?

Comment: Through sed its possible?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answers to my questions.

Comment: Needed , should be removed from col3 and can be replaced with space

Comment: So, does the `awk` example I gave do what you want? If not, does `awk '{gsub(/,/,"",$3)}1' the_file`? Please [update the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76466904/edit) and put the exact expected output in it.

Comment: What you show is not a valid CSV by any accepted norm/standard and if it were the solution would be to quote the field, not remove the commas from it. You say "and keep , separated values." but the input you show doesn't have comma separated values. I think you may be trying to show us some representation of your data that you think will be useful somehow rather than your actual data.

Comment: The code you tried [tr -d \' | sed "s/<table_name>.//g" | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' >](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76466904/removing-specific-character-from-specific-column-in-unix-file#comment134830310_76466904) appears to have absolutely no relationship to the sample input you posted.

Comment: @Ma28 you should put this question back as it was when  you got the answer you accepted. If you post a new question with a [mcve] that includes some truly representative sample input/output that covers your worst cases then maybe we could help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) I suggest using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) for this. Since the columns are separated by one or more whitespaces, you can use the global substitution function `gsub` on the third column.

This replaces `,` (the regex `/,/`) with an empty string (`""`) in the third column (`$3`):

```
awk '{gsub(/,/,"",$3)}1' the_file
```

Output with the data shown in the question:

```
col1, col2, col3 col4
abc, efg, hij lmn
```

If you want to first remove all commas from the third column, but then add one at the end:

```
awk '{gsub(/,/,"",$3);$3=$3","}1'
```

Which will instead produce this output with the input given:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4
abc, efg, hij, lmn
```

Comment: what does that 1 indicates here "awk '{gsub(/,/,"",$3)}1' the_file".  ? is it number of occurrence. actually its removing second instance of comma (,) but not first instance...

Comment: @Ma28 The `1` is to make it print the line. You could use `awk '{gsub(/,/,"",$3); print}' the_file` instead. Both versions remove _all_ commas from the third column.

Comment: Nope, not working. still seeing first instance of comma like h,j k

Comment: @Ma28 Then there's something in the input not matching what you've shown in the question. I updated the answer with the output I get with your example data.

Comment: My data is like this  "My Name, is, Ma"  need like "My Name is Ma but, coming like "My Name, is ma"

Comment: @Ma28 Please update the question if what you have in the question does not represent your actual data well enough.

Comment: I did now, hope it make sense now ??

Comment: I did changes, but its not reflecting

Comment: No its okay ?? ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254063/discussion-between-ma28-and-ted-lyngmo).

Comment: pluse-uno for tech support (-;! Good luck to all.